# Python3 Imports Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

So... I am attempting to teach myself Python.

In such, I am attempting to build something that I appear to have no clue about...

I have a "workingdir" structure such as:

```
/
-- classes/
-- -- install
-- myfile
```

In `myfile` I am simply attempting to "import" the file `install` by using:
`import classes.install`

Which fails with: `ImportError: No module named 'classes.install'`

I have attempted the following as well, and all end the same way, with the same error:

`import .classes.install`

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
import classes.install
```

As well as putting an empty `__init__.py` file inside the classes directory

the file `install` simply contains:

```
class gyo_install():

    inst = False

    # check if we have everything we need installed.
    def __init__():
        print("Hello World")
```

What am I doing wrong?  I've searched and searched and searched, everything I see points to the same solutions I've attempted, and none of them work.

Comment: Suggest renaming myfile to myfile.py and install to install.py. Then try `import classes.install`.

Comment: Thanks Ron.  That did do the trick, but I wonder why?

Comment: Because python is not automatically recognizing python syntax but needs the scripts to be suffixed with `.py` when scanning for the imports.

Comment: @RonNorris can you answer the question, instead of comment, so I can accept it?  Please throw in a why as well, for future searchers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python looks for files with a .py extension when importing modules. So a file named myfile will not be recognized simply by the command `import myfile`. The pythonic way to ensure that the interpreter will find the module is to ensure it has a .py extension. Renaming myfile to myfile.py and install to install.py and then changing the import command to

```
import classes.install
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create `__init__.py` inside install directory.

Explanation: You can import from a file that is in your current directory or from a package. A package is a directory with `__init__.py` inside. In fact, a package can contain only this single file.

You can read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) for further information.